# Inner self-join with counts based on different criteria

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have a table that partially looks like:

```
CustomerID — the key
Employee — the employee that signed up the customer   
StartDate — the date someone became a customer    
Status — the status of the customer, represented by an integer.
```

There's one integer, -5, that's "bad" and 4 other integers are differing stages of "good". If they've proven to be fraudulent, they get a -5.

I want a query that returns something like:

```
Employee   |  FRAUDULENT | NOT FRAUDULENT  | TOTAL CUSTOMERS
-------------------------------------------------------------
mshreck            100             37               137
fwmurnau            27             10                37
```

So each row contains a count of records after a certain startDate that have been marked fraudulent (have a value of -2), not fraudulent (anything other than -2), the same of the two. And I want a row for each Employee.

Right now, I have to run two queries and use Excel to join them together. I haven't used inner joins on a table itself, but this feels like it would be a possible solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So fraudulent is represented by -5 or by -2? I mention both.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   Employee, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN Status = -2 THEN 1 END) AS FRAUDULENT 
         SUM(CASE WHEN Status <> -2 THEN 1 END) AS NOT_FRAUDULENT
         COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_CUSTOMERS
FROM     MyTable
WHERE    StartDate >= :mydate
GROUP BY Employee;
```

Comment: Missing the from clause

Comment: Thanks, Shadow. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need self join, just use sum() insted of count() with some tweaks to get the numbers:

```
select employee, sum(if(status=-5,1,0)) as fraudulent, sum(if(status<>-5,1,0)) as notfraudulent, count(*) as total
from table group by employee
where stardate>...
```

Comment: Missing WHERE clause  with date condition. And so we get to the same solution :)

Comment: So much thanks to everyone. I didn't learn what I thought I would, but I did learn something! Thanks.